# Can Typescript consume Existing AMD's?

Tags: dojo, typescript, js-amd

Dojo 1.8 already defines AMD modules.  For example you can do things like this:

```
require(["dojo/_base/lang"], function (lang) {
  var ab = lang.mixin({a: 1}, {b: 2});
});
```

But how to I avoid getting an error when I attempt to import this module?

```
import lang = module ("dojo/_base/lang");
```

Is is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a typescript definition file for lang. Assuming that `lang.d.ts` exists in the same directory as `lang.js` this code:

```
import lang = module('dojo/_base/lang')

var ab = lang.mixin({a: 1}, {b: 2});
```

compiled with

```
tsc --module amd yourfile.ts
```

generates

```
define(["require", "exports", 'dojo/_base/lang'], function(require, exports, __lang__) {
    var lang = __lang__;
    var ab = lang.mixin({a: 1}, {b: 2});
}
```

If you don't want to have to match up the directory structures for whatever reason do this instead. Assuming `lang.d.ts` is in in a subdirectory called `3rd` that is a sibling of `test.ts`.

*test.ts:*

```
///<reference path="3rd/lang.d.ts"/>
import lang = module('dojo/_base/lang');
var ab = lang.mixin({a: 1}, {b: 2});
```

*3rd/lang.d.ts:*

```
declare module 'dojo/_base/lang' {
...
}
```

generates the same as above.

Comment: This works...but what if it is dojo/store/Memory which has a constructor?  Can not export constructor so it needs to be contained in a class definition (I guess).  Then import Memory = module("dojo/store/Memory") requires Memory.Memory() instead of Memory().  Can you flesh out a Memory.d.ts to include the constructor?

Comment: NOTE: you *can* export a constructor by using an nameless function.

Answer (score 0):

You can normally load modules via the dojo loader, you don't have to use the import statement. But if you want you have to declare the module:

```
declare module "dojo/_base/lang" {
  export function ...
  export class ...
}
```

Comment: I understand that I can load modules in the same way that I show in the question but how would I do this from typescript so that it appears in the outer require of the generated js?